# Linux error after swapon -a: cannot find the device

Tags: linux

Please give me advice on how to solve the error below.

Linux details:

Kernel version: 2.6.18

Linux-OS-5.3

Thanks

```
 # fdisk -l | grep /c0d0p6
   /dev/cciss/c0d0p6           31790       33845     8385898+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
 # mkswap /dev/cciss/c0d0p6
   Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 8587153 kB
 # echo '/dev/cciss/c0d0p6 none swap sw 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
 # swapon -a
   swapon: cannot find the device for LABEL=SW-cciss/c0d0p6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
mkswap -L SW-cciss/c0d0p6 /dev/cciss/c0d0p6
```

**Edit**: could you try changing the fstab entry you describe above to read

```
/dev/cciss/c0d0p6 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Comment: hi I get mkswap -L SW-cciss/c0d0p6 /dev/cciss/c0d0p6
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 8587153 kB
LABEL=SW-cciss/c0d0p6, no uuid  , and after swapon -s I dont get anything -:(

Comment: how to make fallback to swap procedure?

Comment: Could we see the whole of your /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 11):

> `sudo swapon -a`

I got this;

```
 swapon: cannot find the device for UUID=03599533-3a7e-453c-99d2-dd9470e336fe
```

then I tried

> sudo swapon /dev/sda12

that being the address of my swap partition on my device although not absolute. It worked like a charm. I hope that works for you too.

Comment: To locate the swap partition: `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 2):

Use the command

```
$ blkid
```

It will show you the  list of all partition and their respective UUID

Copy the UUID of the swap partition

Use the command

```
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Enter your root password. Then, in that file replace the existing UUID with the copied UUID from blkid

hit  ctrl+o , hit enter, then hit ctrl+x

restart your computer

Comment: Thank you, this is THE solution to fix the broken UUID reference to the swap volume.